# Store CopyCopter Results Locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, copycopter

Following the Railscast episode on [copycopter](http://railscasts.com/episodes/336-copycopter), so I set up my copycopter server on heroku.  Everything works great, until AWS goes down and brings down heroku.  At that moment, all my copycopter text reverted to the default text I had entered on my html pages.

Is there a way I can store the results from a successful call to my copycopter server on my rails server so that, in case of another heroku outage, my text will still be from copycopter?

Comment: I thought Copycopter synced data from the main server so it didn't have to hit the network every request. Are you saying it reverts back to original settings if the host from which its trying to sync is down?

Comment: That's the behavior we experienced yesterday when heroku was down. I was with you, I thought some sort of syncing took place, but our site, which had the correct text for a couple days, reverted back sometime yesterday while heroku was unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use I18n cache by passing a cache store or even I18n memoization? In my Rails app, I  have `I18n::Backend::Simple.include(I18n::Backend::Memoize)` in an initializer, so all the translations are cached in memory after the first hit.
I18n also supports using a real cache store so you could use memcached or redis to store the copies which would avoid the issue you mentioned when copycopter server goes down.

From [copycopter readme](https://github.com/copycopter/copycopter-ruby-client), you can also export the blurbs:

> Blurbs are cached in-memory while your Rails application is running. To export all cached blurbs to a yml file for offline access, use the rake task:
>
> `rake copycopter:export`
>
> The exported yaml will be located at `config/locales/copycopter.yml`.

Comment: Any ideas on how to read from that yml file once it's exported?

Comment: This seems to only export the keys that are cached so it doesn't sound it can be used for failover... Have you tried to use the rake task to see if you have any keys cached at all? Your problem sounds like they keys were not cached hence why it reverted to the default text instead of using the cached values so using Memoize or a cache store as mentioned above may solve your problem.

Comment: That rake task worked.  Maybe I reset my servers and forgot about it during the Heroku downtime.  Thanks for the leads

Comment: Cool, glad that it helped. Best.